# Async Task Network Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating an android application that uses async task to login and send data(HTTP Post Request. The application works fine when internet connection is good but when logging and it takes too long to post data due to slow connection the application force closes. i would like to display a toast "Error in Connection" when this happens. Please Help

Comment: I'd suggest you to add android tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

Your application probably crashes, because you are trying to show Toast not in a UI Thread. That is you always should make any changes to UI by using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), or within onPostExecute() method, which also runs in UI Thread.

How to catch exceptions in doInBackground's thread and represent them in UI Thread is another question, I can suggest you this solution:

```
private class LoginTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, JSONArray[]> {

    private static final int NETWORK_NO_ERROR = -1;
    private static final int NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE = 1;
    private static final int NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET = 2;
    private static final int NETWORK_TIME_OUT = 3;
            // You can continue this list...

    Integer serverError = NETWORK_NO_ERROR; 

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show(); // Don't forget to create it before

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray[] doInBackground(Void... v) {
        JSONArray[] result = null;
        try {
            result = NetworkManager.login(/* All params you need */);
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            return null;
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            serverError = NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET;
            return null;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            serverError = NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE;
            return null;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            serverError = NETWORK_TIME_OUT;
            return null;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // ..
            return null;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // ..
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ..
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray[] result) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (result != null) {
                    processAndShowResult(result);
                } else {
                       switch (serverError) {
                           case NETWORK_NO_ERROR:
                   Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Probably, invalid response from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              break;
                           case NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET:
                               // You can customize error message (or behavior) for different type of error
                           case NETWORK_TIME_OUT:
                           case NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE: 
                   Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Error in Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              break;
                       }

                }
    }
}
```

By this means, you can flexibly control network errors and undertake appropriate actions, according to these errors.